# Redirect user to home page if type not existing url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to redirect "logged in" user to home page if user type not existing url. I have a service named "authService" where I can check if `user auth ==  true` or `false`.

I use `$STATE.GO` to redirect to login page if user is not auth ( `authService.auth == false`).

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {

        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("login");
    });
}]);
```

Now I want to make similar to redirect user to home page, when user is `auth == true`. When user with token, try to type not existing url, redirect to home page.

I try to do this with inject authService service and make if/else. 
But this isn't working because I get an error

> Error: $injector:unpr
>   Unknown Provider
>   Unknown provider: authService

```
 app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', 'authService',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, authService) {
 if (authService.auth == false) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {

        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("login");
    });
    }
else {
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {

        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go("home");
    });

 }
}]);
```

Is this bad solution? Can I inject custom service to app.config? Can someone pls help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this on the `run` function and use the `$stateChange` events:

```
app.run(['$state', '$rootScope', 'authService', function($state, $rootScope, authService) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function(event, toState) {
        if (toState.name !== "home" && !authService.auth) {
            // Prevent going to the state
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go("home");
        });
    });
}]);
```